# Bits Reserved For The Network

Tags: java, sockets, network-interface

How can I find the number of bits reserved for the network portion of the address?

Here is my code in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ifaces;
    ifaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (ifaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface iface = ifaces.nextElement();
        System.out.println(iface);

        // loop through all of the (potential) IP addresses configured to use "iface"
        Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = iface.getInetAddresses();

       // Showing teh value, either ipv4 or ipv6
      // and the number of bits reserved for the network portion of the address

        while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {

            InetAddress address = addresses.nextElement();
            String hostAddress = address.getHostAddress();

            System.out.println("addr: " + address.);

            if (address instanceof Inet4Address && !address.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                System.out.println("IPv4: /" + hostAddress);
            }
            else if(address instanceof Inet6Address && !address.isLoopbackAddress()){
                System.out.println("IPv6: /" + hostAddress);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Example of output I should get:

```
name:lo0 (lo0)
    IPv6: /fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0, 64 bits reserved for the network
    IPv6: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0, 128 bits reserved for the network
    IPv4: /127.94.0.1, 8 bits reserved for the network
    IPv4: /127.0.0.1, 8 bits reserved for the network
```

How am I to get number of bits reserved for each mac address?

Answer (score 1):

IP addresses and MAC addresses are two separate things.

For what you want, you would need the corresponding subnet mask for each IP address. That will tell you which bits of an IP are for the network portion. However, you cannot get a subnet mask from an `InetAddress`, so try using [`NetworkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getInterfaceAddresses()) instead. [`InterfaceAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InterfaceAddress.html) has [`getAddress()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InterfaceAddress.html#getAddress()) and [`getNetworkPrefixLength()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InterfaceAddress.html#getNetworkPrefixLength()) methods:

> Returns an InetAddress for this address.

> Returns the network prefix length for this address. This is also known as the subnet mask in the context of IPv4 addresses. Typical IPv4 values would be 8 (255.0.0.0), 16 (255.255.0.0) or 24 (255.255.255.0).
>
> Typical IPv6 values would be 128 (::1/128) or 10 (fe80::203:baff:fe27:1243/10)